# (Soft question) Well-ordering principle is "non-algebraic"

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

The following quote is from the wikipedia page for the Well-ordering principle.

> Garrett Birkhoff and Saunders Mac Lane wrote in A Survey of Modern Algebra that this property, like the least upper bound axiom for real numbers, is non-algebraic; i.e., it cannot be deduced from the algebraic properties of the integers (which form an ordered integral domain).

Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle

I have a couple of questions.

Is there another definition of "non-algebraic"? I find the one provided confusing.

How would one prove that a property is non-algebraic?

Are there any other properties that are non-algebraic?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think that it is only a "metaphor"... The point of view of (modern) algebra is on *structures*, defined by axioms: the axiom of e.g. *commutative rings* are common to many "domains", and not only that of integers. These axioms define the "algebraic" properties of the structure.

Comment: The well-ordering p is a form of induction, and thus it is not common to every domain of objects satisfying the above algebraic properties, but is specific of numbers. It cannot be derived by the "algebraic" axioms: in this sense it is called "non-algebraic".